# $_POST not showing a form element hidden by jQuery

Tags: php, html, post, hidden-field

I have a form that uses jQuery to hide fields that are not relevant unless certain conditions are met:

```
<form action="thepage.php id="subform" method="post">
      <h2>
        Select a Drawing Type:
      </h2>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="drawingType" tabindex="10" value="1"/>Drawing 1
        <input type="radio" name="drawingType" value="2"/>Drawing 2
        <input type="radio" name="drawingType" value="3"/>Drawing 3
        <input type="radio" name="drawingType" value="4"/>Drawing 4
      </div>
      <p class="drawingInput drawX">
        Is this drawing related to an old drawing?
        <input type="radio" name="revUp" tabindex="100" value="0"/>No 
        <input type="radio" name="revUp" value="1"/>Yes
      </p>

  <input type="submit" name="submitted" value="New Drawing" />
</form>
```

With the jQuery:

```
$('.drawingInput').hide;
$('input:[name="drawingType"]').change(function(){
  if ($(this).val()==1){
    $('.drawingInput').hide();
    $('.drawX').show();
  } else if ($(this).val()==2){
    $('.drawingInput').hide();
    $('.drawX').show();
  } else if ($(this).val()==3){
    $('.drawingInput').hide();
  } else if ($(this).val()==4){
    $('.drawingInput').hide();
  } 
});
```

So when Drawing 1 or 2 is selected, the next input button is revealed.  The user then selects `revUp` field, and submits, with everything working okay.  However, if the `p` is never revealed such as by not selecting value 1 or 2 in the first radio box, `revUp` is never $_POST'ed, with evidence of `var_dump($_POST)`.

How can I retrieve the value of `revUp` if the user never sees it?  It shows up in the var_dump when it is visible, but not when it has never been selected.  Same is true for the console reader, checking the headers sent.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a browser specific thing. Try showing them to the user, but with 99.99999% opacity or something like that, and see if the values are sent then.

On the other hand: do you really need to send them if they're never edited by the user? Doesn't that mean you know their values anyway?

Comment: I have tried it in both Chrome and Firefox (latest versions) and get the same responses.  I am using the value for a logic statement.  I would rather determine the next course of action based soley upon `revUp`, rather than add extra logic.  It will be more portable.  The opacity idea is interesting, but semantically not correct.